# insert list,values into mysql table

Tags: python, mysql

I need to insert the list,some values into table

I have tried executemany but it's not worked.

```
list1=['a','b','c','d','e',['f','g','h','i']]

query="insert into "+metadata_table_name+"(created_by,Created_on,File_Path,Category,File_name,Fields) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" # inserting the new record

cursor.executemany(query,list1)
```

list should be entered into the last(Fileds) Column

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error message? If yes, please include it. If not, please explain what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about data types. Does MySQL have a suitable data type for python's nested lists? I don't know such types.
A possible solution is to use JSON encoding and storing the lists as strings in MySQL table. Encode last element of your list to JSON string:

```
import json


list1=['a','b','c','d','e',['f','g','h','i']]
query_params = list1[0:-1] + [json.dumps(list1[:-1])]
query="insert into "+metadata_table_name+" .(created_by,Created_on,File_Path,Category,File_name,Fields) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)" # inserting the new record
cursor.executemany(query, query_params)
```

For using stored data later you have to convert back JSON string to  a list:

```
fields_list = json.loads(fields_str)
```

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: It's working now, when I change cursor.executemany to cursor.execute